# custom field not blank conditional issue

Tags: conditionals, textarea

I've created the following conditional which is displaying 0 content:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="patterns" orderby="title" status="pending|camera-ready|closed|open"}
{if oldnotes != "" }
    <ul>
    <li>{title}</li>
    </ul>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I know there are a couple hundred entries with this field so I'm wondering what is wrong. It is just a text area field.

Comment: Are you on a page that is relative to the entries you're trying to pull in? If you're not then you'll need to be sure to add the dynamic='no' parameter to the exp:channel:entries tag.

Comment: I am making a page simply to check for content there so I can move it and delete the field. I had not added the dynamic="no" so I went back and did it but field still resolving empty.

Comment: Have you tried what Mattsidjohn suggested?

Comment: I just tried both ways and still resolving no results.

Comment: Is oldnotes a text or textarea field? Try this: {exp:channel:entries 
 channel="patterns" 
 status="pending|camera-ready|closed|open"
}
 {count} of {total_results}
 {if oldnotes}
      --- {title}
 {/if}
 <br>
{/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: This is getting there! I am now seeing "1 of 100 
2 of 100 
3 of 100 
4 of 100 
5 of 100 
6 of 100 
7 of 100" just not the actual title of the article..

Comment: also it is a text area field

Answer (score 1):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="patterns" orderby="title" status="pending|camera-ready|closed|open"}
{if "{oldnotes}" != "" }
    <ul>
    <li>{title}</li>
    </ul>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

That should give you the results you need, or you could use this method.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="patterns" orderby="title" status="pending|camera-ready|closed|open"}
{if oldnotes}
{if:else}
    <ul>
    <li>{title}</li>
    </ul>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I would also suggest you try to use

```
{if no_results}
   <p>Hello World</p>
{/if}
```

To test your entries tag is returning results.

Comment: The first ex resolves empty even though I know there are multiple entries with info in the field. The second way shows me all the entries where oldnotes is blank and I tried adding {if "oldnotes" == "" } so that I see the reverse however then I get no results..

Comment: add the parameter dynamic="no" and try my first example if statement.

Comment: I have tried that and it's still resolving no content.